# Async Function Call Inside While Loop

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a queue which stored on Redis lists. I'm trying to create async consumer for this queue. But couldn't call async function inside loop. Its working like sync function when I call.

```
import asyncio

async def worker():
    print("starting sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("slept")

async def main():
    while True:
        await worker()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is a short and simple example of mine implemantation. I'm expecting to see 'starting sleep' messages until first 'slept' message, it means for 2 seconds.

Comment: You `await worker`, so nothing inside `main` will progress until `worker` is done… What else did you expect?

Comment: I'm just excepting to see "starting sleep" messages until first "slept" message, which appears after 2 secs. So "starting sleep" messages for first 2secs after run. @deceze thanks for attention

Comment: No, for this you'd need to keep launching many workers without `await`ing them, *but* you'd also need to put *some* `await` inside `main`, otherwise nothing else could ever run. An `await` puts a "break" into the code which allows other code to run. There's only one thread and tasks are *cooperatively multitasking*. Meaning, whenever a task `await`s the completion of something else, it yields control back to the event loop, which will schedule other tasks to run in the meantime.

Comment: Use [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) to run workers in parallel and block until all are complete.

Comment: Yes, I want to spawn them in parallel. But couldn't find anything how to do in practically. When I call them via asyncio.wait or directly, raising you never awaited error as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` is literally `await`ing the completion of `worker`. Until `worker` is done, `main` won't progress. `async` tasks don't run in the background like in multithreading.

What you want is to keep launching new workers without `await`ing each one of them. However, if you just keep doing this in a loop like this:

```
while True:
    worker()
```

then you will never see any output of those workers, since this is an endless loop which never gives anything else the chance to run. You'd need to "break" this loop in some way to allow workers to progress. Here's an example of that:

```
import asyncio

async def worker():
    print("starting sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("slept")

async def main():
    while True:
        asyncio.ensure_future(worker())
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This will produce the expected outcome:

```
starting sleep
starting sleep
starting sleep
starting sleep
slept
starting sleep
slept
...
```

The `await` inside `main` transfers control back to the event loop, which now has the chance to run the piled up `worker` tasks, When those worker tasks `await`, they in turn transfer control back to the event loop, which will transfer it back to either `main` or a `worker` as their `await`ed sleep completes.

Note that this is only for illustration purposes; if and when you interrupt this program, you'll see notices about unawaited tasks which haven't completed. You should keep track of your tasks and `await` them all to completion at the end somewhere.

Comment: Now I can see my failure clearly. I'm already using await in **main** because of aioredis. Just I should spawn workers in background. Just changed it and everything working great. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @deceze, your solution has helped me to understand and solve my requirement partially. Thanks for that. As you mentioned in the task how to track the tasks that are still pending. My script is running fine for sometime and stopping without completing all the awaited tasks. Thanks.

Comment: is there a difference between `ensure_future()` and `create_task()`...  ie.  in both cases, just doing the same thing => creating future tasks ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `asyncio.wait`:

```py
import asyncio

async def worker():
    print("starting sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("slept")

async def main():
    tasks = [worker() for each in range(10)]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

It spawns all the workers together.

Comment: I need to create workers dynamically because I need them when recieved a task from redis queue. deceze's answer covering my issue complately. Thanks a lot for your time too.